# CI/CD keeping images up to date in production

Tags: docker, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment, continuous-delivery

I have a scraper service that calls invokes a `docker run` as a subprocess on docker-images containing scraper applications/code. Currently I have to ssh into the cluster to manually rebuild the images anytime there is an update made to any of the scraper applications.

My question is what is the most suitable way to integrate this into a CI/CD flow. Currently I have steps to build the images and push it to a registry but how do I automate the update onto the cluster/server or what is the best approach to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Currently I have to ssh into the cluster to manually rebuild the images anytime there is an update made to any of the scraper applications.

The simplest thing is to automate this manual process, and add it to your CI/CD pipeline. Write a script, and run it against the remote cluster/server as part of your pipeline.

---

As your process matures, you'll be looking at tools like [Kubernetes](https://kubernetes.io/), [AWS EC2 Container Service](https://aws.amazon.com/ecs/), [Rancher](https://rancher.com/), [Docker Swarm](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/)... the list goes on. These are considered *container orchestration tools* and one of their jobs is gracefully handling the deployment of many, many containers for you.

Deploying containers is the tip of the iceberg with any of these products, though. I suggest you start with automating the process you're having to do manually right now, and the rest will follow as it's needed.